# Getting today's data from Oracle DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, oracle12c

I am trying to get data from Oracle 12c DB based on the value in column defined as "Timestamp(6)" and nothing is returned. I tried different variations of binding the parameter all to no avail.

The issue is, I believe, a C# DateTime variable (dtSelectedDate) is passed to the function executing the query and it shows as "05/14/2021 12:00:00". However, records for that day (May 14, 2021) in the database  are listed as "05/14/2021 00:00:00.000000000"

```
public DataSet GetIDCLogData(int iLogType, DateTime dtSelectedDate)
{
    List<OracleParameter> spParams = new List<OracleParameter>();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string sWhere = string.Empty;
    string sQuery = "SELECT A, B,C, D " +
        "FROM REQRESPLOG " +
        //"WHERE LOGTYPEID = :LogTypeID AND LOGDATE = :LogDate";
        "WHERE LOGTYPEID = :LogTypeID AND LOGDATE = TO_TIMESTAMP(:LogDate, 'mm/dd/yyyy')";

    try
    {
        spParams.Add(new OracleParameter("LogTypeID", OracleDbType.Int16, iLogType, ParameterDirection.Input));
        //spParams.Add(new OracleParameter("LogDate", OracleDbType.TimeStamp, dtSelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), ParameterDirection.Input));
        //spParams.Add(new OracleParameter("LogDate", OracleDbType.Date, dtSelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"), ParameterDirection.Input));
        spParams.Add(new OracleParameter("LogDate", OracleDbType.Varchar2, dtSelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + " 00:00:00", ParameterDirection.Input));
        dbContext.Open();
        dbContext.ExecuteOraAdapterFillCmd(sQuery, spParams, ref ds);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        dbContext.Close();
    }
    return ds;
}
```

Comment: Use `OracleDbType.Timestamp` the way you have in the comment, but don't call `ToString` on the value. Use the `Date` property if you need midnight on that date.

Comment: Didn't help. I think it is something with "12:00:00" in C# date time variable. User selects May 14, 2021 from calendar and variable passed to API is "05/14/2021 12:00:00" whereas in database the rows have "14-MAY-2021", no time just date.

Comment: As long as the column is a temporal value and it is at midnight (or you've trimmed it to midnigh) and you're passing a `DateTime` value at midnight (using the `Date` property if needed), they will compare equal.

Comment: The whole "12:00:00" vs. "00:00:00" issue only applies if you're using strings somewhere. Don't do that with date/time values. And don't confuse representation with value.

Comment: Problem was caused by an idiotic mistake that only happens late Friday afternoon. However, since you replied and I actually learnt something from it, change it to an answer and I will mark it.